# Why aren't my asp identity stored procedures being created in my database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I normally build my application's data model into the existing ApplicationDbContext when I'm using ASP.NET Identity. This usually builds the database with all the tables and stored procedures and ASP.NET Identity 2 needs (such *aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion*)

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    // DbSet items go here to define the application's data model.

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("OrtundConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Problem is I'm getting an error later in execution that says the `aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion` Stored Procedure doesn't exist and sure enough, checking the database, it isn't there.

I'm building the database in the normal way using Migrations:

1. Enable migrations
2. Add a migration
3. Update database

Why aren't my stored procedures being created? Am I missing something? Can I create them manually after I create the database?

Comment: I know it's only a workaround , hence not an answer but yes i would try creating manually afterwards. Not perfect but my two pence. It's the way i would get around it, i have spent days debugging identity problems in the past only to be defeated in the end :)

Comment: I don't even know how I'm supposed to create these stored procedures manually since I don't know what they do

Comment: have you tried running aspnet_regsql.exe ? I'm not sure if it's even used in 2 but worth having a search on some other posts i know its been asked before. Are you sure Identity 2 even uses stored procedures? it's been a while but i don't remember any being created.

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/2048614.aspx?Could+not+find+stored+procedure+dbo+aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion+

Answer (score 1):

I don't think ASP Identity 2 uses stored procedures. That stored procedure used to be generated using the `aspnet_regsql.exe` tool but I believe this is now redundant. It sounds as though you possibly have a mismatched schema to the version you are trying to use. ASP.NET Identity 2 only uses tables.

https://forums.asp.net/t/2048614.aspx?Could+not+find+stored+procedure+dbo+aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion+